# How to filter each index in a query with two indexes in Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to make a query to fetch information on two different indexes in Elastic:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must" : [{
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [{
             "match" : {
               "action": "VoiceQueueAbandonAction"
              }},
              { 
              "match" : {
                "action": "QualifyVoiceWel"
              } 
             }     
           ]
          }
         }
       ],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "created_at": {
            "gte": "2022-05-04 00:00:00",
            "lte": "2022-05-04 23:59:59"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's coming correctly, but it's duplicating information, because in the index "qualifications" and "queueevents" there is the same action "QualifyVoiceWel".

In this case, I would need to filter that the "QualifyVoiceWel" field came only from the qualifications index and not from queueevents either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `bool` clause inside existing `should` like below:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "action": "VoiceQueueAbandonAction"
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "action": "QualifyVoiceWel"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "_index": {
                          "value": "qualifications"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "created_at": {
            "gte": "2022-05-04 00:00:00",
            "lte": "2022-05-04 23:59:59"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options based on your requirements:

- Query against proper index by /<index_name>/_search

OR

- Index name is available to use in queries as `_index`. [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html) documentation gives more details